# How to use offline mapbox for my specific qml application?

Tags: qt, qml, mapbox-gl

I cloned mapboxgl from Github. I followed the steps.
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/qt

The map running when I enter the make run-qt-app command on mapbox-gl-native directory. But I would like to include the offline map on my qml application to implement via qt creator.

How can I do it? Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That repository contains code for the Qt bindings and should not be used directly.

Use the "mapboxgl" plugin available since Qt 5.9. There you can specify the path for the offline database:

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/location-plugin-mapboxgl.html#optional-plugin-parameters